# How to renable javascript confirm pop up in Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I accidently disabled JavaScript confirm window in Edge for a website and now I am unable to find the setting to reenable it. You know the one where it asks something like "Are you sure you want to do it" with OK and CANCEL buttons as well as checkbox to never show this again.

How to reallow it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel, open Java, go to the Security Tab, and then at the bottom Exception List, click on Restore Security Prompts.  It is a Java and not Edge issue.

Comment: I don't see any Java option in Control Panel.

https://i.imgur.com/s6EDGnE.png  

https://i.imgur.com/wmFm5lm.png

Comment: You are using the Categorized view of Control Panel. Go to the bottom left (Programs) and expand that. Java is in there. Then reset Security as I posted.

Comment: No it's not there.